# Javascript function returns a string instead of user inputs

Tags: javascript, function, substring, concatenation

I am trying to split and invert user inputs within a function, i.e. ( Cat Food = Fot Caod) However, instead of returning the actual function data, it is returning one long function string. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

```
    var mixUp = prompt("Enter a word")
    var mixUp2 = prompt("Enter a second word")


    function myFunction(mixUp, mixUp2) {

       var mixUp = mixUp.substring(0,2)
       var mixUp2 = mixUp2.substring(0,2)

       var myFunction = mixUp.concat(mixUp2);

      return myFunction

      }


    document.write(myFunction)
```

Comment: You are returning the function. Name the variable myFunction differently.

Comment: You'll need to revise how functions and function parameters work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Move `prompt` functions inside your function.
- Don't name returned variable exactly the same as the function's name (to avoid name conflict).
- Call the function.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var mixUp = prompt("Enter a word");
  var mixUp2 = prompt("Enter a second word");
  var mixUp = mixUp.substring(0, 2);
  var mixUp2 = mixUp2.substring(0, 2);

  return mixUp.concat(mixUp2);
}


document.write(myFunction())
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the logic of the function but ,

what you are doing wrong is that you are writing a function object to the document

you just need to call it and supply the mixUp and mixUp2 arguments

```
var mixUp = prompt("Enter a word")
var mixUp2 = prompt("Enter a second word")


function myFunction(mixUp, mixUp2) {

   var mixUp = mixUp.substring(0,2)
   var mixUp2 = mixUp2.substring(0,2)

   return mixUp.concat(mixUp2);

  }

document.write(myFunction(mixUp , mixUp2))
```